# My text does not display

Tags: java, android, file, text

I have a text file that I want to display. When I run the app, just a white screen is displayed, without the text.

```
String text = "";

try {
       InputStream is = getAssets().open("matthieu.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView_mat.setText(text);
```

Comment: Try debugging the value of `text` before setting to the text view. Any exceptions in the log?

Comment: Try running just `textView_mat.setText("hello");` and see if that works.

Comment: Are you on the main thread?

Comment: Are you on the main thread? Yes...

Comment: Answer the other comments too. And add `Log.d("ReadText", "text = " + text);` before the setText line and check your logcat.

Comment: @Steve Smith, It works

Comment: @All, the file.text doesn't display. I just have a white screen

Comment: I changed from a raw (Main/raw/file) to assets (Main/assets/file) now it works...Thanks RobCo